# Kotlin array too big? Internal compiler error

Tags: android, kotlin

I built an app which displays a random image everytime you launch the app.

Everything worked fine, but since the array containing the drawable paths contained approximately more than 6000 items, I get an error while building the APK.

Is the array limited to a certain amount of items and is there another way of doing it?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.randomimages

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val images = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.image1,
            // ...
            R.drawable.image8829
        )


        image1.setImageResource(images[Random.nextInt(images.size)])
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="121dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="219dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Error**

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during file facade code generation
File being compiled: file://C:/Users/User/AndroidStudioProjects/randomImages/app/src/main/java/com/example/randomimages/MainActivity.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$OutputClassFile.asByteArray(ClassFileFactory.java:315)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:247)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:634)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error generating class file com/example/randomimages/MainActivity.class (compiled from [C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\randomImages\app\src\main\java\com\example\randomimages\MainActivity.kt]): Method too large: com/example/randomimages/MainActivity.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$OutputClassFile.asByteArray(ClassFileFactory.java:315)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.output.OutputUtilsKt.writeAll(outputUtils.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.access$writeOutput(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$createOutputFilesFlushingCallbackIfPossible$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationStateKt$GenerationStateEventCallback$1.invoke(GenerationState.kt:353)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.state.GenerationState.afterIndependentPart(GenerationState.kt:310)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:71)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: com/example/randomimages/MainActivity.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeMethodInfoSize(MethodWriter.java:2089)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:458)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBuilderFactories$2.asBytes(ClassBuilderFactories.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(DelegatingClassBuilderFactory.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.synthetic.codegen.ParcelableClinitClassBuilderInterceptorExtension$ParcelableClinitClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(ParcelableClinitClassBuilderInterceptorExtension.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.synthetic.codegen.AbstractAndroidOnDestroyClassBuilderInterceptorExtension$AndroidOnDestroyClassBuilderFactory.asBytes(AndroidOnDestroyClassBuilderInterceptorExtension.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$ClassBuilderAndSourceFileList.asBytes(ClassFileFactory.java:347)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassFileFactory$OutputClassFile.asByteArray(ClassFileFactory.java:312)
    ... 46 more


> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during file facade code generation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error message is:

> **Method too large**: com/example/randomimages/MainActivity.**onCreate**

There are two possible approaches, which are both less abusive than what you have there:

---

A) Move `val images` into a [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    ...

    companion object Images {
        val items = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.image1,
            // ...
            R.drawable.image8829
        )
    }
}
```

---

B) The ideal would be, to define this as an `array` in the resources:

```
<array name="images">
    <item>@drawable/image1</item>
    <item>@drawable/...</item>
    <item>@drawable/image8829</item>
</array>
```

Alike this, the array could be accessed just anywhere, not only in `MainActivity`.

Besides, it should be soon enough to set the image `.onCreateView()`.

Comment: This tip helped me out ... thx ... why not in MainActivity? I moved my list from MainActivity to another one and no error anymore. I like to understand why?